# ImportError while importing djorm_pgfulltext

Tags: python, django, full-text-search

Installed the djorm-ext-pgfulltext using the command

```
pip install djorm-ext-pgfulltext
```

And tried to import this for full text seach in django

```
from djorm_pgfulltext.models import SearchManager
```

Then I get this error

```
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

How can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That error doesn't depend on the new library you installed. The official [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/settings/#designating-the-settings) (link is for Django 1.3) give you some solutions to your problem. The fastest way is to `EXPORT` the variable:

```
# Example for Unix Bash Shell
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings
django-admin.py runserver
```

Another way is adding the following lines to your project's `__init__.py` file:

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myapp.settings'
```

How's your project structure? Are you experiencing this error with every new django project you're creating? Adding your project root to `PYTHONPATH` env variable is also a viable solution for you.